# SVN alternative

Tags: svn, version-control

HI! I started writing some complex C# project. I'm writing it alone. The bad thing is that i'm writing that project piece-by-piece, step-by-step so some of my code is written on my home computer, some parts of code are written on my computer at work and i have HARD TIME tracking which version of project is newest! You know, after few months of pause, i have no idea which project is most recent: the one on my flash disk, or home computer or work computer, i have no idea what classes were changed and how...it's a mess!

That's why i started using SVN (AnkhSvn + TortoiseSvn) but IT'S TOO COMPLEX for me! I expected something which could be learned "by the way", in few minutes! I'm developing that app alone, i'm not planning to turn in anybody else, is there any simple alternative for SVN? I need some simple ("instant","no-brain") system for online code storage with just "upload changes" and "download changes" features.

Do you know anything like that?

Comment: The question is impossible to answer if you don't explain what the problem with SVN was. SVN is generally considered to be fairly easy to use, so I doubt anyone will be able to propose something "simpler" without knowing where you had problems.

Comment: well i had troubles with maintaining my "local svn folder", when i change something outside of Visual Studio sometimes i got errors when i try to commit the changes, then when I update my SVN folder some of files are deleted but error when comitting remains. I just expected something more straightforward, without need to spend much time learning how to use it. That's why i complained that SVN is too complex. Need some version control system for lazy programmers :)))

Comment: If you actually want version control learning SVN by reading [the freely available SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) will be well worth your time. I've used two or three other VCSs and their principles are usually similar to or more complex than SVN.

Comment: Alternatively if you're determined not to learn SVN, keep one copy of your code on a memory stick that you use in both places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use and enjoy [Git](http://git-scm.com), but I have heard very good things about [Fossil](http://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) for exactly the kind of irritations you mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

If it should be any simpler than Subversion, you could consider coding the entire app in your [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/) folder.

Comment: A little trade-off : Dropbox does not do versionning -> only synchronising. BTW you are limited to 2GB in the free version.

Comment: Dropbox does as a matter of fact do versioning :) Right click on any item in your dropbox and click 'Dropbox' > 'See previous versions'.

Comment: Really? Did not know about that. To what extends does it work? 1, 2 versions? (BTW I should check that against storage usage as well)

Comment: Don't know if there is a max, but I've got documents in my dropbox with up to 30 versions.

Answer (score 2):

Use only TortoiseSvn (without AnkhSvn). It should be 100% sufficient in your case and you will have half less learning.

Still SVN but it is worth learning even for one-man (non-trivial) projects.